# spread operator on object react redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using redux with react.

I am updating the state which looks like this

```
state = {
    album: {
      name: 'Blood, Sugar, Sex, Magik'
      date: '1991',
      artist: 'RHCP'
   }
}
```

The relevant part of my reducer looks like this

```
case 'UPDATE_ALBUM_NAME_SUCCESS':

    return {
        ...state,
        album: {
            ...album,
            name: action.name,

        },

    };
```

`action.name` is `'Californication'`

I want to just update the album name, however, my code is deleting all the other parts of `album` and just leaving the `album.name`. Can anyone advise how to do this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `...state.album` instead of `...album`.